# CSS3 radial-gradient not working on fire fox?

Tags: css

This radial gradient is not working on firefox:

background-image: -moz-radial-gradient(bottom center, 900px 900px, #7dd134 0%, #137f1e 90%, #137f1e 100%);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is Mozilla`s bug they do not support defined size radial gradient.
Here  is the bug report: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=627885

Comment: Don`t forget to accept an answer if it answers your question.